# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception when using CircularFifoQueue

Tags: android, apache, android-studio

I'm trying to use the class CircularFifoQueue
It compiles successfully but I got the following exception on runtime

```
stack=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue;
```

although I added the collections4 dependency to the build.gradle

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0'
```